# Share ssis package/solution to another person

Tags: mysql, ssis

I need help please, I have created ssis package, still in development stage, I need to send to another person so that it can be checked/ edited before it get deployed, 
I didn’t check in yet, what is the steps to share it with someone else with out deploying it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you created the package, it asked you for a directory to store the Visual Studio solution.  You could just give them the copy of the solution directory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, So like my own directory, like c;\name\   Would it let them see the whole project?

Comment: It should....the directory should contain the solution file (sln) and everything else required to compile the project to a dtsx file.

Comment: Thank you so much!